# How can I hold common runtime data in cocoa app?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I am new to cocoa and mac os x development. 
Different components of my app use a particular location to store data etc, The location is determined at the start of the app. For example a subdirectory directory in the user's home directory , temp directory of the system etc and similar runtime information that is used by different classes in my cocoa app. This information should be determined at the start of the app once and reused later.

Every component should be able to access a central component to get this information rather than each one calculating over and over again.

Does cocoa provide some place to hold this data ? or Do we create singleton object ? any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common pattern for accessing shared model resources is a through a singleton model controller class, like you wrote. Here's how I manage creating/accessing singletons:

```
+ (id)sharedInstance {
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    static SomeModelControllerClass * sharedInstance;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^ { sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init]; });
    return sharedInstance;
}
```

The function `dispatch_once` guarantees that a given block of code identified by the `dispatch_once_t` token "once" is only executed once.

The other, more important, question is how to create/store the data that your model controller will manage. There a couple of options:

1. **Keep it all in memory** If you have a relatively small amount of data that can be held in memory all at once, and regenerated with ease on each app launch, then this is the simplest way. It is probably not a good user experience though.
2. **NSCoding** Have your model objects implement the NSCoding protocol methods (init/encode withCoder). Your model controller will be responsible for writing/reading your model stack to /from disk at appropriate times (preferably on a background thread). This technique makes sure your user sees some data immediately upon launch, but it requires that all data be held in memory after it's read from disk. It's a good technique for an app like Twitter, and indeed they used this technique for many years.
3. **Core Data** Core Data is a great choice for "shoebox" style apps with lots of data that needs to be stored locally and is too large to keep in memory all at once. It comes with a big learning curve and lots of boilerplate, so I only recommend this if you can't keep all your model objects in memory at once.
4. **Custom Storage** There are many third-party frameworks for doing what Core Data does without the headache. Most of them are built on SQLite. Explore Github for options that appeal to you. [YapDatabase](https://github.com/yaptv/YapDatabase) looks like the coolest one to me.